# Insert(SpyOn 2 times) jQuery value to input during Jasmine tests

Tags: jquery, jasmine

Hi i have a works tests

```
it("should add a model", function() {

    spyOn($.fn, "val").and.returnValue("Bar");

    foodtype.addNewFoodtype(); //My view 
    expect($("#newFoodtype").val()).toEqual("Bar");
    expect(foodtype.collection.length).toEqual(1);

});
```

on next test when I  set

```
spyOn($.fn, "val").and.returnValue("Bar");
$("#newFoodtype").val()
spyOn($.fn, "val").and.returnValue("Foo");
$("#newFoodtype").val()
```

to checking a change but have a error

> Error: spyOn : val has already been spied upon
>           Usage: spyOn(object, methodName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You'll just need to return a new value instead of spying on it again.
- Here is how I modified your code to make it work.
- assigned a variable to spy so that I can access it once again
  `spyObj.and.returnValue("Foo");`
- Please note that I've used a dummy view `foodtype` which mimics your view.

  ```
  var foodtype = {
    addNewFoodtype: function() {
      $("#newFoodtype").val("some val");
      this.collection.push("some val");
    },
    collection: []
  }
  describe("multispy demo", function() {
    it("should add a model", function() {
      var spyObj = spyOn($.fn, "val").and.returnValue("Bar");
      foodtype.addNewFoodtype(); //My view 
      expect($("#newFoodtype").val()).toEqual("Bar");
      expect(foodtype.collection.length).toEqual(1);
      spyObj.and.returnValue("Foo");
      expect($("#newFoodtype").val()).toEqual("Foo");
    });

  });
  ```